# How to override HostID in Azure Functions v4

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am working on migrating some azure functions from v3 to v4 and when I switch `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION:~4` Function Host Name Collision Check is failing, with following error:

> Function Site Name is over 32 Characters long
>
> Recommendation:
>
> ...
>
> If it is not possible to add AzureFunctionsWebHost__hostid (V2+) or id
> (V1), the only other option is to reduce the length of the site name
> to less than 32 characters. As there exists no means to rename a
> function, the customer must therefore, delete and recreate it with a
> new compliant name.
>
> ...

However, I am struggling to find the way to specify Host ID.

I tried adding `AzureFunctionsWebHost__hostid` and `AzureFunctionsWebHost:hostid` settings:

[image]

I even tried adding `id` property to `host.json`:

```
{
  "id": "qwertyuiopas1234a",
  "version": "2.0",
  ...
```

But it still fails name collision check.

**Question: What am I missing here?**

Comment: Hi @Vladimirs, did you ever solve this one? I'm running into the exact same thing on my FA after upgrading to V4.

Comment: @Coxy unfortunately, I didn't find a solution on this one, I just ended up giving up since I know that I am not going to run into host name collision problem with this particular project.